# Flash instance name

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I use AS3 and I wanted to know if there were a function or a way to create objects and there instance name inside a for or while loop.
This is to create like 15 objects with different instance names without having to create each one of them alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s:Sprite;
var i:uint;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    s = new Sprite();
    with (s) { // with allows you to access variable directly inside scope
        graphics.beginFill(0xffcc00);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
        graphics.endFill();
        width = 10;
        height = 10;
        x = i * 10;
        y = i * 10;
        name = "sprite"+i; // instance name
    }
    addChild(s);
}
```

You can create any (display)object like this. If you want to retrieve later one of those sprites, then use getChildByName("instancename") function.